# Upload Log files to different server : Laravel

Tags: laravel-4.2

I want to upload my laravel logs to different server except last log.I want to keep my last log file in local and other log files to different server. Any one have idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a bash script that will use `scp` to copy what you want from the source to destination. Then use Laravel to trigger that script.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy